# How to refresh the jwks_uri?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a jwks_uri which I have setup in an application i.e. "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<'id'>/discovery/v2.0/keys" which is constant in my case when fetching it from "https://login.microsoftonline.com//v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration".

How can I perform a manual rollover/refresh for the jwks_uri in Azure AD?

I tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/signing-key-rollover doc but I get failed at
`Connect-MgGraph -Scope "Application.ReadWrite.All"
Connect-MgGraph : Invalid JWT access token.
At line:1 char:2

- Connect-MgGraph -Scope "Application.ReadWrite.All"
- ```
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-MgGraph], AuthenticationException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Authentication.Cmdlets.ConnectMgGraph`
  ```

I am expecting that my application should fetch the key and should be readily available for any rollover.